# request.getParameter doesn't work for PUT or DELETE

Tags: java, post, httprequest, put, http-delete

If `request` is an `HTTPServletRequest` why can I use `request.getParameter` to get the body for a `POST` request, but not for a `PUT` or `DELETE` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Put method is disabled as mostly we use Get and Post in regular jsps and servelts. But, it can be easily configure to support it.
First, in order to allow Tomcat to accept commands other than HTTP GET and PUT we should add to Tomcat’s web.xml the following init param:

You can follow this below post for more explanation and set up.

http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html

Comment: Is this specific to Tomcat?

Comment: web.xml file is not specific to server ,it is specific to app.